# How can I get "music channels within a channel” on YouTube API v3

Tags: android, api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

The YouTube channels can have lists of several "related" channels. For example, the Music channels & ALSO get channels videos.(channel list with channels video)like.: 
- Top Tracks
- New Music This Week
- Latest Music Videos
- Pop Music
- Electronic Music
- Pop Music
- Latin Music
- House Music
- Hip Hop Music
LIKE THAT.....

Music Channel: http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ

i want to above link channel(category) wise data

Related Channels to the Music Channel: http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ/channels

Answer (score 0):

Use the video category list 10 for Music as listed in [this Github page](https://gist.github.com/dgp/1b24bf2961521bd75d6c):

Here's the full list

```
2 - Autos & Vehicles
1 - Film & Animation
10 - Music
15 - Pets & Animals
17 - Sports
18 - Short Movies
19 - Travel & Events
20 - Gaming
21 - Videoblogging
22 - People & Blogs
23 - Comedy
24 - Entertainment
25 - News & Politics
26 - Howto & Style
27 - Education
28 - Science & Technology
29 - Nonprofits & Activism
30 - Movies
31 - Anime/Animation
32 - Action/Adventure
33 - Classics
34 - Comedy
35 - Documentary
36 - Drama
37 - Family
38 - Foreign
39 - Horror
40 - Sci-Fi/Fantasy
41 - Thriller
42 - Shorts
43 - Shows
44 - Trailers
```